# Rust pcap lib download "Windows"

Tags: rust, sdk, environment-variables, packet-capture, npcap

I have A problem to install Pcap lib from the rust crates
I have downloaded the npacp-1.76.exe, and already download the SDK they requested, I go to the environment variables and I don't see any Variable called "LIB" so Added it both for the user and system variables and the needed path, but when I tried the packet capture on the default device

```
use pcap::Device;

let mut cap = Device::lookup().unwrap().unwrap().open().unwrap();

while let Ok(packet) = cap.next_packet() {
    println!("received packet! {:?}", packet);
}
```

and for some reason there are no packets it's just like a true while loop so I tried to print all the dvices names(description) and some of them just came out like "Microsoft" and I don't know why please help.
:)

I tried this code block to try and print the description of the devices ->

```
fn main()
{
    let devices = Device::list().unwrap();
    for device in &devices{
       println!("{:?}" device.desc.unwrap());
    }
}
```

but for some reason this was the result
"Microsoft"
"Microsoft"
"VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter"
"Microsoft"
"VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter"
"Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller"

what is Microsoft device?

i think that the location I put the sdk may be wrong

Comment: You might be more interested in `device.name` than the `desc`.